# Bubblesort giving access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, file, sorting, bubble-sort

Hi everyone I am trying to finish a assignment for class where I need to sort a File full of employees by their ID number. There are 10 lines in the file each with an employees info. The order is ID LASTNAME FIRSTNAME

The program ran fine before I wrote the sort function and copied all the data properly into the array, but now after adding my sort function I keep getting a access violation with no hints as to what is causing it.

I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    int _id;
    string _lastName;
    string _firstName;

    Employee()
    {
        _id = 0;
        _lastName = "n/a";
        _firstName = "n/a";
    }
};

void copyFile10(Employee [], int);
void sortFile10(Employee [], int);
int main()
{
    const int size10 = 10;
    Employee employees10[size10];

    copyFile10(employees10, size10); //1.fill array/copy file
    sortFile10(employees10, size10); //2. sort

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void copyFile10(Employee employees10[], const int size)
{
    ifstream data10("data_10.dat");
    for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++) //1.fill array/copy file
    {
        data10 >> employees10[count]._id;
        data10 >> employees10[count]._lastName;
        data10 >> employees10[count]._firstName;
    }
    data10.close();
}

void sortFile10(Employee employees10[], const int size)
{
    Employee buff1;
    Employee buff2;
    int counter = 0;
    bool ordered = false;

    while (ordered == false)
    {
        for(int count = 0; count < size-1; count++)
        {
            if(employees10[count]._id > employees10[count+1]._id)
            {
                buff1._id = employees10[count+1]._id;
                buff1._lastName = employees10[count+1]._lastName;
                buff1._firstName = employees10[count+1]._firstName;

                buff2._id = employees10[count]._id;
                buff2._lastName = employees10[count]._lastName;
                buff2._firstName = employees10[count]._firstName;

                employees10[count]._id = buff1._id;
                employees10[count]._lastName = buff1._lastName;
                employees10[count]._firstName = buff1._firstName;

                employees10[count+1]._id = buff2._id;
                employees10[count+1]._lastName = buff2._lastName;
                employees10[count+1]._lastName = buff2._lastName;

                counter++;
            }
            if(counter == 0)
            ordered = true;
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When your program crashed under the debugger, surely you had a callstack available?

Comment: Did it crash on this line? if(employees10[count]._id > employees10[count+1]._id); 'count+1' is 10, but the max array index is 9.

Comment: That is probably it Mark Stevens, but it doesn't show me what line it is. I'll try to find a solution and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @sircrisp It's a common mistake with bubble sorts & programming 101. You compare "this" entry to the "next" entry, but let the loop run all the way to the end, when it should be end-1. And yeah, the debugger should have plopped you right on that line.

Comment: No luck I changed count < size to count < size-1 and am still getting an error pointing at pvBlk = _heap_alloc_dbg_impl(nSize, nBlockUse, szFileName, nLine, errno_tmp); in dbgheap.c

Comment: Can you go through the loop line by line and check at what function it breaks? Its not that the heap implementation is wrong, but the code itself looks fine. And, can you please post your updated code?

Comment: Does the program crash under the non-debug version of the heap allocator?

Comment: Your 'swap' can be coded as `buff1 = employees10[count]; employees10[count] = employees10[count+1]; employees10[count+1] = buff;`. But that's not the problem.

Comment: A couple suggestions on style. First, the compiler generated an assignment operator for `Employee`, so the detailed assignments in the swap code can be replaced with simpler ones such as `buff1 = employees10[count+1];`. Second, you can swap two values with only one temporary. And third, you can swap two values with `std::swap`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the access violation, but simplifying the swap as @PeteBecker suggests shows that the basic layout of the sort is wrong (and eliminates a firstName/lastName bug). You set `ordered = true` the first time two neighboring elements are in order, so the bubble sort quits early.

Comment: I guess the compiler was having some kind of bug because I restarted and pasted the code and it runs now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            if(employees10[count]._id > employees10[count+1]._id)
```

What happens here on the last iteration of the loop (i.e. when `count` is 9)?

Comment: I've fixed this but I am still getting an access violation

Comment: @sircrisp - so the the original code is not the code that's now having a problem. Show the fixed code!